# Changing Visual state of an Entry from code behind

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have been trying to change Visual State of an Entry from CodeBehind.
so if the entry is disabled , background color should be changed to Grey and if its normal , it should be white which is clearly defined in styles.xaml ,Based on User input, I make a call  VisualStateManager.GoToState(Entry, "Disabled");or  VisualStateManager.GoToState(Entry, "Normal"). Once It is disabled where the background color changes to Grey , I could not change the background color anymore even when I forcefully set it or when I call the VisualStateManager. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in .NET 7. I checked it is not reproducible in .NET 8 anymore, so feel free to upgrade your project to .NET 8 according to this guide:

[Upgrade MAUI from .NET 7 to .NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Upgrading-.NET-MAUI-from-.NET-7-to-.NET-8)

Comment: Thank you ! I came across this as well , I will try and update you if that works !

Comment: marking it as accepted !

Comment: Glad to hear that it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below on how to implement the [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-8.0) in code behind:

```
var vsg = new VisualStateGroup() { Name = "CommonStates" };
var vs_list = new VisualStateGroupList();

var vs_nor = new VisualState { Name = "Normal" };
var vs_dis = new VisualState { Name = "Disabled" };   
var vs_fo = new VisualState { Name = "Focused" };

vs_nor.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.White });
vs_dis.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.Grey });
vs_fo.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property=BackgroundColorProperty, Value=Colors.Green });

vsg.States.Add(vs_nor);
vsg.States.Add(vs_dis);
vsg.States.Add(vs_fo);
vs_list.Add(vsg);

// myEntry is the name of the Entry in xaml
VisualStateManager.SetVisualStateGroups(myEntry, vs_list);
```

Comment: It was changing everything except the background color , font size and font color changes but once it is sets the background color for disabled , it never changes the background color alone

Comment: @Suraj Consider upgrading your VS to the latest version and choose .NET 8.0 framework when creating the projec to see if background color works. If it failed, you can report to github:github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Comment: Sure ! Thanks for info , I will do the same.

Comment: @Suraj Thanks for the update, looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @Alexander - You are right , that resolved the issue !

Comment: @Suraj Thanks for the update, glad to see it works.